# How to change text color

Tags: javascript

I want to change the innerHTML text here to white:

```
<div id="Achievements" class="style5 a1" style="color:#FF0000">&#149; Comment 1 Post</div>
```

I'm not sure how to do it with pure JavaScript. Use the class set 'a1'.

```
function achievements() {
if (TotalCoal >= 1) {   

}
}
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` text is just a string with no formatting concept. You mean to change the CSS color (just helping you Google for it later).

Comment: Downvoted because of lack of research. A simple Google query would answer your question within seconds.

Comment: @Zabri, there was no lack of research at all. nothing i found worked (4 Google Pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a1');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

To fetch a single element via the id:

```
document.getElementById('Achievements').style.color = '#FFFFFF';
```

Comment: @brainbowler, the id Achievements is not the class a1.

Comment: @brainbowler, so how would i add this to an functional if statement? Statement will be added to my question above.

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you wanted to change the color of elements with class "a1". where do you want to place an if statement? what do you want to check?

Comment: what's the point of checking TotalCoal outside the function where you are incrementing it? I inserted my code in your addCoal() function and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/r4egu/5/

Comment: sorry but the point is that i need it to change only if TotalCoal = 1 and none other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the inline styling of the `div`, which is fairly simple.

Just iterate through all of the elements with the class `a1` and set their `style` attribute:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("a1").length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("a1")[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

This adds `style="#FFFFFF"` to each element, which sets the text color to white.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/dm27x/)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change the colour of your text is you can have a button that calls a function when clicked

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_color()
        {
            document.getElementById("sampletext").style.color= '#FFFFFF';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:yellow;">
    <div id="sampletext"><p>This is a sample</p></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="change_color()">Change</button>
</body>
```

This is considering you want to do it with a button. another way is to use Css to change the colour by just hovering over the text with your mouse. but ill let you figure that out, hope it helps :)